# SwiftUI: Why do I get the same pattern of random items in an array?

Tags: swift, random, swiftui, shuffle

I'm working on my project and there's a section where you can test yourself on Japanese letters. You tap a button that plays a sound of a letter then you choose the right button out of three with the correct letter. there are 10 questions in total and it should always randomize, the letters but whenever you come back to the view, the first question is always the same. after the first one it randomizes the rest of the questions but the first question always has the same pattern of letters. What I want is getting a random pattern of letters for the first question every time you come back to the view. I'd appreciate any help.

here's the code of QuestionView:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct HiraganaQuiz: View {
var hiraganas: [Japanese] = Bundle.main.decode("Hiragana.json")

@State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...45)
@StateObject var soundplayer = Audio()
@State private var answer = ""
@State private var counter = 0
@State private var correctAnswerCounter = 0
@State private var showingAlert = false
@State private var alertMessage = ""
@State private var disabled = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.darkBackground
            .ignoresSafeArea()
     
    VStack {
        Text("\(counter) / 10")
            .padding(.top,40)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size:30).bold())

        Text("Tap the speaker and choose the right letter")
            
        Button {
            soundplayer.playSounds(file: hiraganas[correctAnswer].voice1)
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "speaker.wave.3.fill")
        }
        .font(.system(size:70))
       height: 110)
        
        HStack {
            ForEach (0...2, id: \.self) { index in
                Button {
                    letterTapped(index)
                } label: {
                    Text(hiraganas[index].letter)
                }
            }
            .disabled(disabe())
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 35).bold())
           
        Text("\(answer)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.bottom,20)
            .font(.system(size: 30))

        Button {
            resetTheGame()
        } label: {
            Text("Next")
        }.buttonStyle(.plain)
         .font(.system(size: 30).bold())
         .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
         
    }
}
.alert("⭐️ Well done ⭐️", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
    Button("Retry", action: reset)

    } message: {
         Text(alertMessage)
    }
} .onAppear { hiraganas =   Bundle.main.decode("Hiragana.json").shuffled() }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this even compiles -- it should be giving you an error about trying to initialize state like this.

Instead, you can shuffle in the properties in the property initializer:

```
struct HiraganaQuiz: View {
    @State private var hiraganas: [Japanese] = Bundle.main.decode("Hiragana.json").shuffled()
```

---

Update, to show the request for `onAppear` usage:

```
struct HiraganaQuiz: View {
    @State private var hiraganas: [Japanese] =  [] 

    var body: some View {
       ZStack {
         // body content
       }.onAppear {
         hiraganas  = Bundle.main.decode("Hiragana.json").shuffled()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that cause histograms to be created every time view gets initialised? Wouldn't it be better to have @State property with `onAppear`

Comment: Sorry -- good catch!

Comment: Thank you for answering :) but could you tell me how I can use onAppear for that case?

Comment: `.onAppear { hiraganas = Bundle.main.decode("Hiragana.json").shuffled() }`

Comment: Thank you but I'm still confused, where exactly do I attach the .onAppear?

Comment: Attach it to any element in the view hierarchy. Did you try putting it anywhere?

Comment: @jnpdx IMHO It would be best if you learn the basics of SwiftUI as it would help you in the run.

Comment: @user1046037 I think if you look at my answer history, it’s reasonably clear that I know the basics. If you feel like you have a better answer to offer, please do.

Comment: @jnpdx Yes I've tried to attached it everywhere I could and none worked

Comment: @Schocolate please edit your post and show your attempt

Comment: @jpndx I've changed it. since I wasn't so sure how it worked I tried and attached it on every closed curly brackets ^^; but the one I'm showing got some errors.

Comment: It needs to be attached to one of the View elements inside the body. Can you please try that, format your code, and remove the parts not relevant to the question?

Comment: I removed some code that aren't relevant to the problem. Idk if I did what you told me but this didn't work either...

Comment: You did not do what I suggested. It should be a `@State` variable. If you really want it to be set on `onAppear`, it's default value could be `[]`. What you have now would generate a compiler error. And, you're still trying to set the initial value. I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Also, you remove "some code", but not all that isn't related to the problem. You can also format you code by selecting it and using `ctrl-i` in Xcode. When I do that, I see other compilation errors, so it's quite possible you have more problems than are going to be solved in the scope of this question. Or, it's possible that you've removed some code and led to compilation errors. Hard to tell without a [mre].

Comment: @jnpdx my apologies, I tagged you instead of the original poster, I intended the original poster to go through the basics. My bad am sorry about that